# Time complexity of two different bubble sort method with the same iterations

Tags: java, data-structures

I was implementing a bubble sort algorithm and I was confused whether the two below given java methods will give the same time complexity or will it be different:

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[]) 
    { 
        int n = arr.length;             
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)               
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)         
                
            {
                if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
                { 
                    // swap arr[j+1] and arr[j] 
                    int temp = arr[j]; 
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1]; 
                    arr[j+1] = temp; 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

This method had O(N^2) Time complexity - I am sure about it.

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[]) 
    { 
        int n = arr.length;                                         
        int i=0,j=0;
        while(i<n-1)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
            { 
                        
                int temp = arr[j]; 
                arr[j] = arr[j+1]; 
                arr[j+1] = temp; 
            } 
            j++;
            
            if(j==n-i-1)
            {
                j=0;
                i++;
                        
            }
        }
```

I am not sure about this one as it does the same iteration using single loop ?

Comment: The first ist O(n^2) as you mentioned and the secound is O(n) since there is only one loop.

Comment: They are both O(n^2). @lucas , you have a misconception that every loop iterates O(n) times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both implementations have the same complexity, which is easy to see by comparing the number of their iterations. Let's add counters to places where iterations occur and compare their values after sorting:

```
    class Main  {
    private static int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = new int[]{1, 6, -4, 0, 12, -8}, array2 = new int[]{1, 6, -4, 0, 12, -8};;
        bubbleSort1(array1);
        bubbleSort2(array2);
        System.out.println(count1);
        System.out.println(count2);
    }

    private static void bubbleSort1(int arr[]) {
        int n = arr.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
            ++count1;
            for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; ++j) {
                ++count1;
                if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) {
                    int temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void bubbleSort2(int arr[]) {
        int n = arr.length;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while (i < n - 1) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
            ++j;
            ++count2;

            if (j == n - i - 1) {
                j = 0;
                ++i;
                ++count2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
20
20
```

It is not the number of cycles that is important in complexity assessment, but the algorithm itself, and here it is the same O(n^2).